# How do I load phonegap/cordova with jade?

Tags: node.js, cordova, express, pug

I am developing a Web Application using node.js, express and jade.  I have the following jade template which I am seeing using a WebView in a Phonegap application:

```
doctype mobile
html
    head
        script(src="cordova-2.1.0.js")
        script
            var ready = function() {
                alert(\'Ready\');
            }
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready);
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content
            h1= title
            button(id='vibrateButton', onclick='navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);')Confirm
            #services
                - each service in services
                    div.service
                    a(href=service.link)!= service.name
                    div.desc= service.description
```

What this template will produce is a webpage with a list of items (a description and a link) which will be fetched from a mongo database.  The page is served using node.js

Now, the cordova script is not loading because the alert ("Ready") is not being displayed.  Also, if I hit the button the device won't vibrate and the console will display the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'vibrate' of undefined at http://xx.xxx.xx.x:3000/:5
```

How can I include the Phonegap script using jade? I have tried to load simple scripts with just an alert and it works, but in this case I don't know why it is not working.

Could anyone provide advise please? Thanks.

Comment: Do you compile the jade template to html before you deploy / build?

Comment: @TheHippo No i do not compile the template.  What do you mean by this? I am new using jade and I am not aware of what it means ... I will google it now.

Comment: @TheHippo I've compiled the template and tried to render it with `var fn = jade.compile(data); var html = fn({phonegap:true,title:'Kino Services',services:servs}); console.log(html); res.send(html);` but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

With recent changes to cordova, you should take a look into [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) api. That's the recommended way to deal with remote pages embedded in your application.

In the end, you'll probably have a single index.html on the application to make sure the cordova js api is loaded and everything is ok. Then you'll open an InAppBrowser targeting your remote page (remember to whitelist it on config.xml for a better experience!).

Comment: i am currently using version 2.1.0 of cordova, so it is not a current one.

Answer (score 1):

The dot after the script is missing. Read this:

> "Often you might want large blocks of text within a tag. A good
>   example is with inline scripts or styles. To do this, just add a .
>   after the tag (with no preceding space)"

It's taken from the jade-lang reference.

Example:

```
script.
  if (usingJade)
    console.log('you are awesome')
  else
    console.log('use jade')
```

Will render:

```
<script>
  if (usingJade)
    console.log('you are awesome')
  else
    console.log('use jade')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

these will never work.

the html pages needs to be on the client side( app side ) not in the server side(node).

Example. In a android phonegap proyect on the `assets\www` folder.

i dont know for wat SO is your app, but

**App client side:** views, phonegap, jquery .... and all the stuff to request the data to the node server.

**Server side:** dbStuff, and all the stuff to retrieve the data to the app requests.

hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @3boll actually it works, I have tried to see an html file that includes javascript calls to the android java counterpart in a webview of a phonegap application and it works.